# Responsive images vs Responsive divs

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have the following simple examples with the exact css.

The only difference is the first is an img tag and the second just a div.

I cant understand why with the same css the divs are responsive when minimize the window and the images are not.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjqh6xcy/2/

```
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjqh6xcy/3/

Answer (score 0):

The `width` property doesn't do anything here, because the parent is a flexbox. Use `flex-basis` instead.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  border: solid red;
}
img {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" />
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" />
</div>
```

An awesome guide to flexbox and the properties can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It doesnt change anything